# Syntax to read IA32 register with offset in GDB?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, cpu-registers

I have a GDB syntax question...  I'm struggling to learn IA32 for a course, and GDB is handy for watching registers.  However, too often I see values referred to by a register plus an offset.  For example:

```
cmpl    -8(%rbp), %eax
```

Its easy to see the value in %eax:

```
(gdb) p $eax
$1 = 5
```

and I get that `-8(%rbp)` is "*eight bytes before address stored in %rbp,*" but how the heck do I see that value in GDB?  None of the following work for me:

```
(gdb) p $rbp-8
$2 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe238
(gdb) p $(rbp-8)
No symbol "rbp" in current context.
(gdb) p ($rbp-8)
$3 = (void *) 0x7fffffffe238
(gdb) p 0x7fffffffe238
$4 = 140737488347704
```

I'm expecting `-8(%rbp)` to hold the integer value 7, but I can't confirm that.

BTW, I should have said:  I'm working with GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-80.el7 on my school's Linux server.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

-RAO

Comment: Use the `x` command to examine memory, such as `x/d $rbp-8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `*(int*)($rbp - 8)`. GDB accepts a C-like syntax, the cast is necessary to tell it how many bytes make up the value you are interested in. The dereference is necessary as `$rbp` contains a pointer and you want to dereference that pointer.

Comment: Always happy to help.